# add string to String array

Tags: java

I am new in Java so I need little help

I have

```
String [] scripts = new String [] ("test3","test4","test5");
```

and I want to add new strings ( string1,string2) to this array ( scripts)  for examples

```
String string1= " test1"
String string2 = "test2"
```

I want to add the new string not in the init but in later phase

How I can do it ?

Comment: Can you use `List` (like `ArrayList`)? Or you can create a new array with bigger size, loop in old array add from index = 2. Then add new elements at index `0` and `1`.

Comment: So you are not new to SO, do search before posting question to avoid downvote.

Comment: Go for `java.util.Collections` if you need elements to be modified dynamically. map the requirement and available Collections type. for above, as all suggested, `ArrayList` is preferable.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You cannot resize an array in java.

Once the size of array is declared, it remains fixed.

Instead you can use `ArrayList` that has dynamic size, meaning you don't need to worry about its size. If your array list is not big enough to accommodate new values then it will be resized automatically.

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
String s1 ="Test1";
String s2 ="Test2";
String s3 ="Test3";
ar.add(s1);
ar.add(s2);
ar.add(s3);

String s4 ="Test4";
ar.add(s4);
```

Comment: Make sure to also import java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 25):

First, this code here,

```
string [] scripts = new String [] ("test3","test4","test5");
```

should be

```
String[] scripts = new String [] {"test3","test4","test5"};
```

Please read this tutorial on [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Second,

Arrays are fixed size, so you can't add new Strings to above array. You may override existing values

```
scripts[0] = string1;
```

(or)

Create array with size then keep on adding elements till it is full.

If you want resizable arrays, consider using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 10):

you would have to write down some method to create a temporary array and then copy it like

```
public String[] increaseArray(String[] theArray, int increaseBy)  
{  
    int i = theArray.length;  
    int n = ++i;  
    String[] newArray = new String[n];  
    for(int cnt=0;cnt<theArray.length;cnt++)
    {  
        newArray[cnt] = theArray[cnt];  
    }  
    return newArray;  
}
```

or The **ArrayList** would be helpful to resolve your problem.

Comment: +1 good. Also can use System.arrayCopy

Comment: You can use Arrays.copyOf() to achieve the same.

Answer (score 6):

As many of the answer suggesting better solution is to use ArrayList. ArrayList size is not fixed and it is easily manageable.

It is resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to store the list.

Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically.

*Note that this implementation is not synchronized.*

```
ArrayList<String> scripts = new ArrayList<String>();
scripts.add("test1");
scripts.add("test2");
scripts.add("test3");
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Java arrays hold a fixed number of values, you need to create a new array with a length of 5 in this case. A better solution would be to use an ***ArrayList*** and simply ***add*** strings to the array.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> scripts = new ArrayList<String>();
scripts.add("test3");
scripts.add("test4");
scripts.add("test5");

// Then later you can add more Strings to the ArrayList
scripts.add("test1");
scripts.add("test2");
```