# How to put elements into String array?

Tags: java, arrays

How can i put elements into the following string array?

```
String[] myString = new String[] {};
```

Note: Number of element is not fixed.

Comment: Arrays must be of fixed size. If size is known, you can insert elements this way myString[0] = "somestring" then myString[1] = "someanotherstring" and so on. Use ArrayList if size is not known.

Comment: Do we need to just write like,  String[] myString = new String[] {"element1", "element2".......};  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go through this

[How can I add new item to the String array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518195/how-can-i-add-new-item-to-the-string-array)

and

[add string to String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098032/add-string-to-string-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList.toArray( T[] a )
```

this would give your array you're trying get.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Since `myString` is an empty array and since an array's length is fixed, an empty array cannot be changed.

But what you can do is to store a new, different array in the `myString` variable.